# How to adjust video histogram using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, filter, color-correction

I have a dark video and'd like to adjust its histogram. In a graphical editor I've found the values of the color levels that enhance video contrast.

[image]

How to set this level values in ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [eq filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq).
Example :
`ffplay input -vf eq=contrast=1.25:brightness=.05:saturation=2.5:gamma=1.07`
to determine the good values for you.

Comment: I'd like to adjust histogram exactly as on the picture.